# How do I replace a null value with the text "NULL" regardless of type in Pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a function which will take in every column in the dataframe (there's different types for each one).  basically I'm trying to create an SQL script to insert values into a db from an exported text file, but for items where there is no entry I want "NULL" added.  For strings I need ' at the beginning and end of the field,  My function is as follows:

```
# Add apostrophes if needed to surround the fields, but if blank add "NULL"

    def add_apos(x):
    
    if x.isnull():
        return "NULL"
    elif x.isnumeric():
        return x
    else:
        return "\'"+x+"\'"
```

I've tried multiple versions but I'm unable to get this to work.  I've also tried splitting the function so numeric fields go to another function that caters specifically for numeric fields and another for str objects, but I can't get it to work.

The most frequent error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'
```

Comment: Can you add some sample dataframe input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def add_apos(x):
    if x is None:
        return "NULL"
    elif str(type(x)).__contains__("<class 'int'>"):
        return x
    else:
        return "\'" + x + "\'"


print(add_apos("abc"))
# 'abc'
print(add_apos(None))
# NULL
print(add_apos(10))
# 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,

```
def add_apos(x):
    if x is None:
        return "NULL"
    elif isinstance(x,int):
        return x
    else:
        return "\'" + x + "\'"
print(add_apos(None))
print(add_apos(987))
print(add_apos("qwer"))
```

[image]